# Need SQL outer join help with 3 tables

Tags: oracle, join

See below example. `ID_1` and `ID_A` are primary keys for `table_1` and `table_3` respectively. `Table_2`, the primary key is `ID_1` and `ID_A`. `ID_A` is joined to one and only one `ID_1` via `table_2` due to business rules.

I need a query that will return all rows from `table_1` where the `value_1 = 11` and joined to that, I need *only* the rows from `table_3` that have a `value_a = 'a'` if it joins to a row in `table_1` that has a `value_1 = 11`.

Please see *results required*. Note there is no row

```
|1 | a |
```

in the result set because `value_a` for `id_a = 'b'`;

I've tried a left outer join but all `ID_1` are returned. I've also tried CTE, to no avail. Here's one SQL, I tried.

```
Select ID_1, Value_1, ID_A, VALUE_A
   From TABLE_1 t1
   Join TABLE_2 t2 on t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
   Left Outer Join TABLE_3 t3 on t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A;
```

I've also tried using a temporary table which include only the results from `TABLE_1` that I need, but the left outer join using the temp table still returns the above mentioned row.

The DB is Oracle, but I prefer a standard solution. Also, performance is a consideration, given that `TABLE_1` has over 200 million rows and `TABLE_3` has about 4 times that many.

**TABLE_1**

```
| ID_1 | Value_1  |
-------------------
| 1    | 11       |
| 2    | 12       |
| 3    | 11       |
| 4    | 13       |
```

**TABLE_2**

```
| ID_1 | ID_A  |
----------------
| 1    | a     |
| 1    | b     |
| 3    | c     |
| 4    | d     |
```

**TABLE_3**

```
| ID_A | Value_A |
------------------
| a    | b       |
| b    | a       |
| c    | e       |
| d    | a       |
```

**Results Required**

```
| ID_1 | ID_A    |  Value_1  | Value_A |
----------------------------------------
| 1    | b       |    11     |    a    |
| 3    | <NULL>  |    11     | <NULL>  |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, join `TABLE_2` and `TABLE_3` using an inner join and additionally filtering on `Value_A = 'a'`:

```
SELECT
  t2.ID_1,
  t3.ID_A,
  t3.Value_A
FROM
  TABLE_2 t2
  INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A
WHERE
  t3.Value_A = 'a'
```

This will give you the following result set:

```
ID_1  ID_A  Value_A
----  ----  -------
1     b     a
4     d     a
```

Now use the above as a derived table and join it, using an outer join this time, to `TABLE_1`, additionally filtering the results on `Value_1 = 11`:

```
SELECT
  t1 .ID_1,
  t23.ID_A,
  t1 .Value_1,
  t23.Value_A
FROM
  TABLE_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      t2.ID_1,
      t3.ID_A,
      t3.Value_A
    FROM
      TABLE_2 t2
      INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A
    WHERE
      t3.Value_A = 'a'
  ) t23 ON t1.ID_1 = t23.ID_1
WHERE
  t1.Value_1 = 11
;
```

That will [give you the output you want](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac62c/13):

```
ID_1  ID_A  Value_1  Value_A
----  ----  -------  -------
1     b     11       a
3     NULL  11       NULL
```

However, nesting a query is not the only way to solve your problem – you can also [use a nested join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac62c/12), which is much more concise:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID_1,
  t3.ID_A,
  t1.Value_1,
  t3.Value_A
FROM
  TABLE_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN
    TABLE_2 t2
    INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A AND t3.Value_A = 'a'
  ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
WHERE
  t1.Value_1 = 11
;
```

The last query implements exactly the same logic as the previous query: first, tables `TABLE_2` and `TABLE_3` are joined and the result is filtered, then it is joined to `TABLE_1` and the final set is filtered again. Some people also add brackets around a nested join:

```
FROM
  TABLE_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    TABLE_2 t2
    INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A AND t3.Value_A = 'a'
  )
  ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
```

to make it clearer (perhaps both for themselves and for future maintainers) that the nested join takes place before the outer-level one, logically, although the syntax is unambiguous enough without them.

Nevertheless, many people find it confusing even with brackets, and if you find yourself struggling with it as well, there is [another option – right outer join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac62c/14):

```
SELECT
  t1.ID_1,
  t3.ID_A,
  t1.Value_1,
  t3.Value_A
FROM
  TABLE_2 t2
  INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A AND t3.Value_A = 'a'
  RIGHT JOIN TABLE_1 t1 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
WHERE
  t1.Value_1 = 11
;
```

Again, the logical sequence of events specified by the FROM clause repeats that of the derived table solution: a join between `TABLE_2` and `TABLE_3`, filtered, is followed by a join with `TABLE_1`. The different syntax does not alter the outcome and the results produced still match your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You've obfuscated your question and schema so much that it is very hard for me to understand what you want. Here is a query that should give you the output you want given your sample data or close to it.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID_1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Value_A IS NOT NULL THEN t3.ID_A ELSE NULL END) AS ID_A
    , t1.Value_1
    , MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Value_A IS NOT NULL THEN t3.Value_A ELSE NULL END) AS Value_A
FROM TABLE_1 t1
   LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 on t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
   LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 t3 on t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A AND t3.Value_A = 'a'
WHERE
   t1.Value_1 = 11
GROUP BY
   t1.ID_1
   , t1.Value_1;
```

That is one way you could write it in T-SQL, and I think it will work in Oracle too.

Answer (score -3):

Your SQL is not referencing Alias correctly. If you're doing a JOIN you should reference the source table in your query for OUR sake.

```
SELECT ID_1, Value_1, ID_A, VALUE_A
   FROM TABLE_1 t1
   INNER JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
   INNER JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t2.ID_A = t3.ID_A AND t3.Value_A = 'a'
   WHERE t1.Value_1 = 11 ;
```

Comment: I don't think this will return the result desired when there is not a match with `t3.Value_A = 'a'`